# SQLiteException - no such table

Tags: android, sqlite

Im getting this error when i try to access my View

I've built my database/View using this

```
CREATE TABLE Boxer(
BoxerId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
Firstname NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Lastname NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Match(
MatchId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
BoxerA INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Boxer(BoxerId),
BoxerB INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Boxer(BoxerId),
MatchDate date NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
NumberOfRounds INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT  12
);

CREATE TABLE Round(
RoundId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
MatchId INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Match(MatchId),
BoxerA INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
BoxerB INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
Position INTEGER NOT NULL
);

/*
Building a view which dislpays matches with boxers names and total scores
*/
CREATE VIEW MatchDetail AS
SELECT Match.MatchId, A.BoxerId AS IdA, B.BoxerId AS IdB, A.Firstname + ' ' + A.Lastname         AS NameA, B.Firstname + ' ' + B.Lastname AS NameB,
(SELECT SUM(R.BoxerA) AS Score FROM Round AS R WHERE (R.MatchId = Match.MatchId)) AS ScoreA,
(SELECT SUM(R.BoxerB) AS Score FROM Round AS R WHERE (R.MatchId = Match.MatchId)) AS ScoreB, 
Match.MatchDate, Match.NumberOfRounds
FROM Boxer AS A INNER JOIN Match ON A.BoxerId = Match.BoxerA INNER JOIN Boxer AS B ON     Match.BoxerB = B.BoxerId
```

I've pretty much built my app so far using the notepad example so I then call my DbHelper

```
Cursor MatchesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllMatchDetails();
```

This then calls the query

```
public Cursor fetchAllMatchDetails(){
    return mDb.query(VIEW_MATCHDETAIL, new String[] {
            "MatchId"
            }, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

VIEW_MATCHDETAIL is defined as a string = "MatchDetail"

and it's here where it crashes saying

> no such table MatchDetail: while compiling SELECT MatchId FROM MatchDetail

anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Oh so you know when I run the create script on my local sql database it creates the table and view fine!

Comment: Something that I did find out was that a SimpleCursorAdapter requires a "_id" column so ive also updated my field names for this

Answer (score 2):

You have some beautiful SQL there.  Unfortunately only the first line of sql will be executed in SQLiteDatabase.execSQL.  The rest will be ignored silently (convenient eh?).  Split up the statements manually like this:

https://github.com/browep/fpt/blob/master/src/com/github/browep/nosql/NoSqlSqliteOpener.java

or if you like to keep your sql in a separate file, try this:

```
String sqlText = getSqlText();
for(String sqlStmt : sqlText.split(";"))
     myDb.execSQL(slqStmt + ";");
```

Comment: ha that would go some what to explain when i explore my sqlite database with Questiod it only has a boxer table.. ill try this and see if i get all 3 databases and if so then move onto my view.

Answer (score 0):

What stands out to me is the use of datatypes like `NVARCHAR(50)`. SQLite only has a [very simple set of datatypes](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). I'm surprised it doesn't throw an exception when you install the app. Try using simply `TEXT` instead.

Comment: Then why do they define the set of data types I linked to?

Comment: @mikerobi: SQLite 3 does NOT completely ignore the data type.  It uses it to determine the column affinity.  But there is no difference between `NVARCHAR` and `TEXT`.

Comment: @mikerobi @dan04 Both of your comments were interesting to me none the less. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot access a database that you know you have initialized, try passing the Context from the Activity that created the table to the class trying to query the table.  Use that Context as part of your connection initialization.